# How to associate sharepoint 2013 designer workflow to content type for retention policy using powershell?

Tags: powershell, 2013, designer-workflow

I am having a requirement to write a powershell script which should attache workflow to content type in sharepoint 2013.

basically it is require to create a retention policy which should start a workflow.

any help using powershell?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I resolved this issue by creating a SPD reusable workflow by using sharepoint 2010 template.

Comment: Your question asked for powershell, your answer doesn't provide the solution to your own question.